Aspnet:8.0 Docker Image does not listen on port 8081 when deployed to Amazon ECS
We have a simple web project built using .Net 8.0 and using Docker.  We have made no changes to the default Dockerfile that Visual Studio created
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

When we run this in Docker Desktop we can see it logs two entries
Now listening on: http://[::]:8080
Now listening on: https://[::]:8081

When deployed to ECS (Fargate) it only ever listens on http://[::]8080 and not https.
Does anyone know why?

To be clear, when you look at the ECS task's logs, in CloudWatch Logs, you only see the first Now listening log message for port 8080, and not the second one for port 8081?

EXPOSE is only documentation and doesn't do anything. The default for aspnet:8.0 based containers is to only listen on port 8080, so it sounds like it's doing just that. The weird thing is that it behaves differently locally. Do you run it from Visual Studio? Because VS does things behind your back that aren't super obvious.

@MarkB That is correct.  We only see the listening on port 8080.  We also tried to connect to it using port 8081 and no luck.

@HansKilian we can also run from the powershell command line in docker desktop and both ports are listening.

It seems like there would have to be a difference in the way it is running locally, and on ECS. Either it's not actually the same docker image, or some volume mapping is different, or the CMD or ENDPOINT is being set differently in the ECS task definition, or environment variables are different.

Wanted to post an update as I have managed to solve it and it may help others.
When running the project from Visual Studio, the magic behind the scenes creates the developer self signed certificates and injects them into the kestrel web server.
When running in production this does not happen so you need to manually add the certificates.  Ideally you should use production SSL certificates that are fully valid but in my case for AWS I could not as these were bound to the load balancers and not exportable.
What I did was:

Create a self signed certificate from a private key using openssl.
Converted this into a pfx file using openssl.
Created a folder in the project called Certificates and added the pfx file setting the copy attribute to "Copy Always".  This ensures that on every build the certificate is available locally on the image.
Set the following environment variables in AWS (you can add this to dockerfile though this will expose your password)

ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8081
ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=mycertificatepassword
ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/app/Certificates/ProductionCertificate.pfx
